# Create variables from query within php

Tags: php, variables

Just wondering how the selects from the table can be created into variables. Totally unsure how this can be done. I know with arrays it's quite simple. Somewhat new to php.

Here is my code:

```
    function get($table_name, $conn)
    {
    try
    {
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT archive, projectname, description, clientid FROM $table_name ORDER BY projectname ASC");

        return ($result->rowCount() > 0)
            ? $result // if
            : false; // else
    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

```
    <?php foreach($archives as $archive): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $archive; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any help at all will be great,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you explain again what you want to accomplish? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: you fetch rows of data from your query result, and then stuff that row (which is usually an array) into another array. without knowing what DB library you're using, it's probably somethign like `$data = array(); while($row = $conn->fetch_array()) { $data[] = $row; }`.

Comment: Just trying to display these into a table of rows. And it seems to only print the word "array" instead of the selections. So I thought variables would be the solution, am I wrong?

Comment: if you do `$x = array(); echo $x;`, you'll get `Array` as the output - you cannot echo/print an array directly like that.

Comment: To learn how to iterate over arrays and access their contents, see [`foreach()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or use your favorite search engine to find tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is an associative array then you can use [extract()](https://www.php.net/extract)

```
$size = "large";
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

echo "$color, $size, $shape, $wddx_size\n";

// This will give you 
blue, large, sphere, medium
```

So in your example you can use something like the following

```
extract($result, EXTR_OVERWRITE);

// now you have 
//$archive
//$projectname
//$description
//$clientid
```

However using `EXTR_OVERWRITE`  as PHP will cause:

> If there is a collision, overwrite the existing variable.

**More accuracy toward your goal:**
Assuming the `result array` has more than one row, and you want to fill the arrays

```
$archives = array();

foreach($result as $r){
    extract($r, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME);
    $archives[] = $archive
}
```

Then you can do

```
foreach($archives as $a){
    echo $a
}
```

**Without Using Extract()**

```
$archives = array(); 
foreach($result as $r){

    $archives[] = $r['archive'] // or $r[0]
}
```